# Android Parameters in OnClick function

Tags: android, onclick, textview

I have a table of 16 (4x4) `TextViews`. If one of them is clicked, I want to change its color and mark or unmark it from a boolean array.

In my .xml, the `TextViews` look like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bonus0"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:onClick="ClickTurnColor"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="25sp" 
/>
```

So a click on the `TextView` should start the `ClickTurnColor()` function.
In this function, I need some variables from the `onCreate()` function. 
When I try to pass them as parameters of the `ClickTurnColor()` function, I get errors.

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variables you need outside `onCreate()`, initialize them in `onCreate()`, then use them in the `ClickTurnColor` method. You will have to revert its method definition so it only accepts in one parameter (the View):

```
public void ClickTurnColor (View v)
{
 //implementation
}
```

Also, keep in mind, Java naming conventions dictate that methods should start with a lowercase letter.

Or take the non-xml approach and make the listener inside `onCreate()` if you really must keep those variables local:

```
button.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener () {
  @Override
  public void onClick (View v)
  {
    //use your variables here
  }
});
```

However, now you will have to make those variables `final` if they are not instance variables and you are keeping them local to `onCreate()`.

Also, since you do mention that you have a grid, you coul try using a [`GridView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and use an [`OnItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html). It still comes with the caveats that I mentioned before (either make the local variables non-local or declare them as `final`), but it depending on your needs, it may be cleaner.

Comment: oooh of corse! Thank you :D but when I have 16 TextViews how may I define ONE onclicklistener for all Views?

Comment: @Jokus if using the xml onClick attribute, have all textviews point to the same method. Then inside the method, compare the id of the view with the textview ids. If you're setting the click listener right in the code, sane logic applies. Make one listener or have your activity implement OnClickListerer. Then set each textview's listener to the one you created. Then you will have to do the same check based on Id. I suggest you also look around a bit, this question has been asked before.